# .htaccess redirect everything from directory to a different domain

Tags: .htaccess

We have a WordPress site/single app which serves two domain names: `example.com` and `example.es`.

In our .htaccess file we have currently have the following rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.es
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.exmaple.es/$1 [R=permanent,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

We also need to redirect everything from `example.com/es/...` to `example.es/...`. I have tried multiple examples that I could find, but none of them worked (ended up in 500 server error and empty log), here are a few of them:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/es/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.es/%1 [R=302,NC]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com/es [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.es/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

All of the new rules were placed inside the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: please tell me , do you want only to redirect everything from example.com & example.com/es/ to example.es ?

Comment: Only from example.com/es/... Everything after /es/

Comment: please , see my answer ? if is Ok or let me know what happen

Answer (score 0):

@Domas Hi Domas, the process in your case is to update you site installing some important extension about the domain change.

**Changing the preferred domain name alias WordPress uses**

*If your WordPress* site has a domain name alias pointing to it, and you want WordPress to prefer the alias domain name in links that it generates, you can update the domain name in the WordPress dashboard:

```
Click Settings.
Change the WordPress Address (URL) to the new URL that you want to use.
Change the Site Address (URL) to the same value.
Click Save Changes.
```

You need **WP Super Cache**, this **extension** help you to **update automatically the .htaccess** and change all the needs as you did on you configuration site.
First install the extension https://support.tigertech.net/move-wordpress#updating-htaccess-wp-jmp

Also if you don't need any extension and you want to do by the hand just redirect like this example as needs :

```
#the simple redirection
Redirect 301 /es http://www.example.es/

#Redirect from old domain with subdirectory to new domain
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/es/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.es%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC]
```

It depend of you needs i prefer the last one. Regards

Comment: thanks a bunch for your answer. That's a site translated with WPML, so there is no actual problem with WP. It servers the content for both domains (.COM and .ES). Previously it served spanish pages under example.com/es, therefore we have a lot of "dead links", which I would like to redirect.

Comment: @Domas Welcome, about dead link you got some old WP extension that can help you to fix that problem depend on your version installed but the usefull extension for manage this problem can be found here https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/fix-broken-links/ i use Broken Link Checker. Regards.

Comment: thanks a lot again for your willingness to help, but I do not need any extension, as I just want to redirect the visitors from example.com/es/... to example.es/..., via an .htaccess rule.

Comment: @Domas I just edited and send 2 possibility depends of your needs, may be you need to re adapt on your context, regards.